# Ternary sort never ending program

Tags: matlab, loops, while-loop

I'm am trying to implement a iterative ternary search in Matlab (see below).
When I try to run it, there are no errors generated, but it doesn't finish running (I have to force exit). Chances are, it is stuck in a loop and therefore never finishes running. I can't figure out why it is behaving like that, where am I going wrong?

EDIT: I am in the process of editing the post.
@CrisLuego, I tried to comment on you answer but I was restricted by stack overflow (probably because of my limited reputation)

```
arr = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10];
num=2;
n=10;
loc4 = ternarySearch(num,arr,n);
disp(loc4);

function location = ternarySearch(search_num,array,n)
    i=1;
    j=n;

    while i<j-1
        m1 = round(i + (j-i)/3);  
        m2 = round(i + 2*(j-i)/3);   
        if search_num>=array(m1)
            i = m1 + 1;
            j = m2;

        elseif search_num>=array(m2)
            i = m2+1;
        else
            j=m1;
        end
    end
       if search_num==array(i)
            location=i;

        elseif search_num==array(j)
            location=j;
        else
            location=0;
       end

 end
```

Comment: If you end up in an endless loop, it means that `i` is *always* smaller than `j-1`. Simply store it for the first couple (of thousands) of iterations, plot that, and you can verify that. Additionally: in `while` loops I **always** add a fail-safe condition `iter<max_iter` and increase `iter` on every loop. That way you catch any runaway endless loops (make sure to set `max_iter` slightly larger than the expected maximal run length of course)

Comment: Also, Matlab is an _interpreted_ language. The code can be compiled into  a MEX file, but it's not usually done. Are you really _compiling_ it, or just running it on the interpreter?

Comment: Instead of editing your question in a way that makes my answer look stupid, you could have commented on my answer saying that you've made the suggested change and you still have an issue.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I am still new to stack overflow so I didn't realize there was limit to which you can comment on other's posts. I commented on your answer and got an error that prevented me from doing so.

Comment: @LuisMendo, that is correct, I am just running it on the interpreter

Comment: You should always be able to comment on answers to your own questions. The 50 rep limit doesn't apply there.

Comment: In any case, it's no fun to answer a moving target. Walk through your loop, considering different positions of your searched item, and see what happens in each of the conditional statements. Note that the condition under `elseif` is not evaluated if the condition under the `if` above it is true.